# How can I add an additional word to a URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an application with URLs such as these:

```
https://www.domain.com/example/public/subscription
https://www.domain.com/example/public/subscription/source
https://www.domain.com/example/public/test/subscription
```

I'd like to use mod_rewrite (or some other method) to create shorter "aliases" of the above URLs by removing the `/public/` part so that I can provide my client with these shorter versions of the URLs:

```
https://www.domain.com/example/subscription
https://www.domain.com/example/subscription/source
https://www.domain.com/example/test/subscription
```

In other words, when browsing to `https://www.domain.com/example/subscription`, for example:

- The server must send back the same response that one would get when opening `https://www.domain.com/example/public/subscription` directly
- The browser must still display the shorter version of the URL (without the `/public/`) in the address bar

Is this even possible, and how would such a RewriteRule look like?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this is `.htaccess` file in your `DocumentRoot`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(example)/(.*)$ $1/public/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something else here. The DocumentRoot for this website is /var/www/domain/example and my .htaccess file is in the example/ directory. Right now, I can't even get a simple rule like the following to work: `RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.google.com [R]`. This should redirect a request for `https://www.domain.com/example/public/test/subscription` to Google, correct? Instead, I'm getting 404.

Comment: @Xhantar If your `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/domain/example`, your URLs should look like this: `https://www.domain.com/public/test/subscription` not `https://www.domain.com/example/public/test/subscription`. For this link, `https://www.domain.com/example/public/test/subscription` your `httpd` server is trying to access
`/var/www/domain/example//example/public/test/subscription`.

Comment: @ThinkinMonkey - Aah ok, I see my error now. I was on the right track wrt the actual RewriteRule but the path my DocumentRoot was set to, the base URL in which that resulted and the physical location of my .htaccess file were all factors which I didn't quite grasp. Solved now and working; thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You just want to "remove" the `public` keyword?

Try this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/example/public/(.*) /example/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The other way around, actually (unless I'm confusing myself). I want to provide my client with the shorter URLs and then want mod_rewrite to add the /public/ part, as the application will respond with a 404 Not Found error when calling the URLs without the /public/ (assuming there are no rewrite rules present).